# Control a differential drive robot

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, python, forward-kinematics, differential-drive

I have some questions about implementing a mobile robot. I have an old construction mobile robot wherein this robot the main controller has been removed, and I put in its place a Raspberry Pi 4. I have put Linux and ROS on Raspberry.

I found this library https://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html I managed by sending pulses through the GPIO to have movement on the wheels.

These pulses can be converted to RPM with the appropriate code, so I can also have the wheel speeds in meters per second. Through forward kinematics, I can convert them to angular and linear velocities of the body entirely theoretically.
Is there a way to do this with ROS?

I made a Python script for ROS, which converts linear and angular velocities to wheel velocities, in other words, inverse kinematics.

Can these two coexist so that I can control the robot?

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the donkeycar project. It's an autonomy framework for scale (RC) cars written in Python that supports a number of different kinds of drive trains.  Closed-loop speed control and pose estimation via encoders is in flight (see https://github.com/autorope/donkeycar/tree/921-tachometer-odometer-parts)